# Как правильно отредактировать Google map поиск под Yandex map

Tags: javascript, php, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

подскажите как правильно выставить логическую цепочка, чтобы работало на Yandex map, этот код выводит координаты при нажатие на карту или при поиске адреса в поисковой строке. Сколько не пытался не выходит правильно реализовать.

Вот так выглядит в JS

```
GmapEngine.prototype.searchBox = function (classSearchBox ,func) {
    var me = this;
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(classSearchBox[0]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0, place ; place = places[i]; i++) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
            if(i===0){
                func([
                    place.geometry.location.lat(),
                    place.geometry.location.lng(),
                    me.map.getZoom()]
                );
            }
        }
        me.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}
```

Вот так выглядит в php

```
 if(bookingCore.map_provider === "gmap"){
                    

engineMap.searchBox($('#customPlaceAddress'),function (dataLatLng) {
           engineMap.clearMarkers();
           engineMap.addMarker(dataLatLng, {
           icon_options: {}
                        });
          $("input[name=map_lat]").attr("value", dataLatLng[0]);
          $("input[name=map_lng]").attr("value", dataLatLng[1]);
                    });
                }
                engineMap.searchBox($('.bravo_searchbox'),function (dataLatLng) {
                    engineMap.clearMarkers();
                    engineMap.addMarker(dataLatLng, {
                        icon_options: {}
                    });
                    $("input[name=map_lat]").attr("value", dataLatLng[0]);
                    $("input[name=map_lng]").attr("value", dataLatLng[1]);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Координаты клика всегда есть в событии клика:

```
myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');
}
```

Адрес же в координаты [геокодированием](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode) получать надо:

```
ymaps.geocode('Москва', {
    results: 1
}).then(function (res) {
    // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования.
    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
    // Координаты геообъекта.
    coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates()
});
```